# $\lim\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=0}^n\sqrt{C_n^kp^k(1-p)^{n-k}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $p\in (0,1)$ and define the sequence :
$$a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=0}^n\sqrt{C_n^kp^k(1-p)^{n-k}}$$ where $C_n^k=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.
How can I calculate $\lim a_n$ ? Any help would be appreciated !
Thank you in advance !

Comment: Here’s how I *think* it can work. Consider, for each $a<b$, $I_n(a,b)$ the sub-sum of $a_n$ corresponding to the terms $a\sqrt{n}\leq k-np \leq b\sqrt{n}$. Using the CLT and AM-QM, one can find that $I_n(a,b) \leq (1+o(1))n^{-1/4}\sqrt{b-a}\sqrt{\int_a^b{(2\pi)^{-1/2}e^{-t^2/2}\,dt}}$; and using variance estimates and AM-QM, for any integer $N$, $I_n(-\infty,-N) +I_n(N,\infty)\leq \frac{1+o(1)}{N}$, But $a_n \leq I_n(-\infty,-N)+I_n(N,\infty)+\sum_{k=-pN}^{pN-1}{I_n(k/p,(k+1)/p)}$, and I think this implies that the limsup of $a_n$ is at most $1/N$, which entails that $a_n=o(1)$.

Comment: Actually, you can just replace the sum with $I_n(-N,N)$, it still seems to work.

Comment: There is a sharp peak around $\displaystyle k = np$.

Comment: There is a sharp peak around $\displaystyle  = np$ which yields $\displaystyle a_{n} \sim {2^{3/4}\pi^{1/4}\left(pq\right)^{3/8} \over \color{red}{\large n^{1/8}}}$ as $\displaystyle n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full solution based on my comment, but cleaner:

Let $n$ be large enough, and let $X$ be a random variable with law $B(n,p)$.

We have $\sqrt{n}a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n{\sqrt{P(X=k)}}$.

By AM-QM and then variance estimate, $$\sum_{0\leq k\leq n,|k-np| \geq n^{3/4}}{\sqrt{P(X=k)}}\leq \sqrt{n}P(|X-np| \geq n^{3/4}) \leq \sqrt{n}np(1-p)n^{-3/2} \leq 1.$$

Thus, $a_n \leq n^{-1/2}+n^{-1/2}\sum_{np-n^{3/4} \leq k \leq np+n^{3/4}}{\sqrt{P(X=k)}}$.

By AM-QM, the sum in the RHS is at most $\sqrt{1+2n^{3/4}}\sqrt{P(|X-np| \leq n^{3/4})} \leq 2n^{3/8} \cdot 1$.

It follows $a_n \leq 3n^{-1/8}$ hence $a_n \rightarrow 0$.